# Can I initiate an ivar indirectly?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to initiate my ivar like this:

Declared like this in h-file

```
@interface MyClass: {
    UITextView *_myTextView;
}
```

then created like this in the m-file

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        [self initTextView:_myTextView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initTextView:(UITextView *)textView {
    textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    ...
}
```

_myTextView will still be nil afterwards. **Why is that and what should I do it to make it work?** I've got ARC enabled.

**[EDIT]**

This works. Thanks all!

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _textView1 = [self createTextView];
        _textView2 = [self createTextView];
        _textView3 = [self createTextView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITextView *)createTextView {
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    ...
    return textView;
}
```

Comment: You have to use pointers to pointers to allow the method `initTextView` to change the value of `_myTextView`. See my answer below for a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `[self initTextView:_myTextView];` you pass the current value of _myTextView (which is nil) to your `initTextView:` method. To set the instance variable, you need a pointer to a pointer.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupTextView:&_myTextView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupTextView:(UITextView * __strong *)textView {
    *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    ...
}
```

I also renamed the `initTextView:` method to `setupTextView`, as methods starting with `init` are expected to behave like other `init` methods in ARC.

Comment: Why use pointer-to-pointer when there is a perfectly good return value doing nothing?

Comment: The question was how to initialize the instance variable indirectly. Assigning the return value of a method would be a direct access and as such not answer the question.

Comment: Rubbish. Either method initializes the instance variable, but using a pointer-to-pointer is error prone, over complicated and ugly.

Comment: While both methods initialize the instance variable, only one uses the indirect access for which the question asked. I would also prefer to use the return value of a method, but this was not the question. Besides, using a pointer-to-pointer is not error prone here because of ARC.

Comment: How is it *indirect*?  Because you dereference a pointer?  My understanding is that the OP wants to initialize instance variables outside of his `init` method, which is why he used the term *indirect* as opposed to *directly* in the `init` method.

Comment: My understanding was that the question was how to pass the instance variable as an argument to the method the initializes it, exactly as shown in the (non-working) sample code in the question.

Comment: Thank you Tammo Freese this is indeed the answer I was looking for, but @trojanfoe has the solution I've chosen to implement as it's cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You need to always refer to instance variables using:

```
self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
```

Also use a name other than `initTextView` as methods starting with `init` have special meaning in Objective-C.

If you want to use the same code to initialize multiple text view controls, then use code like this:

```
- (UITextView *)createTextView
{
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    textView.something = whatever;
    ...
    return textView;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.textView1 = [self createTextView];
        self.textView2 = [self createTextView];
        ...
        self.textViewN = [self createTextView];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not needed any more with the latest version of Xcode with `LLVM`.

Comment: @MdaG I have updated my answer with an example of using a method to initialize multiple text views.

Comment: You still do not need to `synthesize` the `property` with the `LLVM` compiler.

Comment: @rckoenes That depends more on style; if you don't want to include the instance variables in the `@interface` part then it makes sense not to bother doing that, however if you want to then it makes sense to use `@synthesize`.  I always include instance variables myself, so I can see what attributes my classes have just by looking at the header file and I think the new shortcut is short sighted.  However it's optional but still legal, so please stop making such a big deal about it.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes you are correct, but Apple does suggest that you just add the property, since there is not need to add the iVar any more this could save you a lot of work.

Comment: @rckoenes I like to include it all; the instance variable, the `@property` and the `@synthesize` but then I'm old skool.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes in the example given by the MdaG there is no property but in the original version of trojanfoe there was a property. Since `LLVM` will automatically add an iVar, with the `_`, there is no need to `synthesize` that property.

Comment: It is plain wrong that you need to always refer to instance variables using a property accessor as the answer above suggests. In fact, with ARC it is much easier to work with instance variables instead of properties.

Comment: @TammoFreese My answer assumes properties have been set-up for the instance variables.

Comment: We don't use @property unless the ivar is meant to be used outside the class hence the underscore convention.

Comment: What is this "special meaning" that init has in Objective C?

Comment: See this section of *Concepts in Objective-C*: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

Answer (score 1):

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        [self initTextView];
    }
}

- (void)initTextView{
    _myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    ...
}
```

if you want to call initTextView for several text views , you can code like this :

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        [self initTextView:_myTextView];
    }
}

- (void)initTextView:(UITextView *)textView{
    //setup the textView
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, but I need to call initTextView for several text views and I'm trying to avoid code duplication.